# Matplotlib Basemap animation taking longer to process with more frames

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, matplotlib-basemap

So I've attached some code that demonstrates what I'm doing. I'm trying to animate this variable in time over a latitude/longitude grid. If I set the number of frames to 5 or 6, it takes less than one minute to run. However this does not scale linearly. If I set the number of frames to 129, it takes ~5-6 hours to process, even on a crude setting. Can anyone tell me how to make it run faster?

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")


#vort='path/vort850.nc'
nc = NetCDFFile(vort)

lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]
vort850 = nc.variables['vort850'][:,:,:]
vort850 = 100000*np.array(vort850)
ntime = len(time)

map = Basemap(projection='cyl',area_thresh=10000, \
        llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')

parallels = np.arange(-90,105,15.) # make latitude lines ever 5 degrees from 30N-50N
meridians = np.arange(-180,180,30.) # make longitude lines every 5 degrees from 95W to 70W
map.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[1,0,0,0],labelstyle="+/-", linewidth=.1, fontsize=6)
map.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[0,0,0,1],labelstyle="+/-", linewidth=.1, fontsize=6)

map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)
map.drawlsmask(land_color='Linen', ocean_color='White')
lons,lats= np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y = map(lons,lats)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdBu')


def title(time_i):
        hours_since="2015-9-30 00:00:00"
        begin=datetime.strptime(hours_since, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        h= timedelta(hours=time_i)
        t2 = begin + h
        print(time_i, t2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
        return t2.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")



def animate(i):
        plt.title('850 hPa Vorticity (Relative)    ' +title(time[i]), fontsize=12)
        vo = map.contourf(x,y,vort850[i,:,:], range(-100,105,5),cmap=cmap)
        print('Current Iteration : ' + str(i))

        if (i==0):
                print('i==0')
                cb = map.colorbar(vo, "right", size="5%", pad="2%")
                cb.ax.tick_params(labelsize=6)
                cb.set_label('Vorticity m/s',fontsize=6)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(),animate,frames=129, interval=1000, blit=False)
anim.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=10, dpi=1200)

exit()
```

Comment: You're adding more and more plots to the figure. So in the first frame you have one contour plot and in the 100th frame you have 100 contour plots. That's why the time it takes grows linearly. You may clear the axes in between, `plt.cla()` to have only one plot per frame.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Wow! Thanks for the response. That makes so much sense. Should I put it plt.cla() in the animate function before I call the title?